# Yii2 - ActiveRecord with relations to array

Tags: yii2

I know there is the answer to use asArray().
But what if I need model from relation and array at the same time?
In this example demoJson is without relations:

```
$demo = Demo::find()->with('bundles')->one();

// view
<?= var demoJson = json_encode($demo) ?> <!-- Using as array ERROR -->
<?= $demo->bundles[0]->someFunc() ?> <!-- Using model OK -->
```

In this example there is no someFunc() because a simple array used:

```
$demo = Demo::find()->with('bundles')->asArray()->one();

// view
<?= var demoJson = json_encode($demo) ?> <!-- Using as array OK -->
<?= $demo['bundles'][0]->someFunc() ?> <!-- Using model ERROR -->
```

So, how to get array from model with all its relations but without using asArray.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try:

```
$demo = Demo::find()->with('bundles')->limit(1)->one();

// view
<?= var demoJson = json_encode($demo->toArray()) ?>
<?= $demo->bundles[0]->someFunc() ?>
```

The `Demo` model could be this:

```
namespace app\models;

use yii\db\ActiveRecord;

Class Demo extends ActiveRecord
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function fields()
    {
        $fields = parent::fields();

        if ($this->isNewRecord) {
            return $fields;
        }

        $fields['bundles'] = function() {
            $bundles = [];

            foreach ($this->bundles as $bundle) {
                $bundles[] = $bundle->toArray();
            }

            return $bundles;
        }

        return $fields;
    }
}
```

Comment: $demo->toArray() is without data from relations (like in Example 1)

Comment: @holden321 You have to rewrite the **fields** function in your **Demo** model. My computer just gong down, I would like to post my answer at a later time.

Comment: @holden321 I have edited my answer. If there are somethings wrong, please let me know.